# jquery ui resizible как убрать стрелки для ресайза

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, jquery-ui, frontend

Как убрать стрелки ресайза с правой и нижней стороны блока. Чтобы стрелка для ресайза появлялась и работала только по ярлычку в правом нижнем углу блока. Или просто только по правому нижнему углу.

Comment: Код в студию!..

Comment: @AGS17, да вроде не сильно надо код. https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#default - блок можно резайзить за треугольник в правом нижнем углу, а ещё за любую из правой и нижней стороны. Он спрашивает, как сделать, чтобы можно было ресайзить только за треугольник (а за стороны - нельзя).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно свойство [`handles`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles).

Свойство определяет объекты, которые будут использованы для изменения размера области. По умолчанию оно имеет значение `'e, s, se'`, что означает:

- `e` — правый *(восток)*,
- `s` — нижний *(юг)*,
- `se` — нижний правый *(юго-восток)*

Вам нужен только `se` — нижний правый

```
$('#resizable').resizable({
  handles: 'se'
});
```

```js
$('#resizable').resizable({
  handles: 'se'
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3>Resizable</h3>
</div>
```